# How to reprint a statement every number of rows

Tags: c

I'm beginner in C
this is my code that prints ascii table in different representation such as decimal, hexadecimal, octal and binary.
and I don't know how to reprint a statement (row) that shows what in column every 20 line or rows.

this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef CHAR_BIT
#define CHAR_BIT 8  
#endif

int main () {

    unsigned char c = 0;     /* for the character */
    int n = 0;              /* integer for the for loop Iteration */
    
    printf_s("\nthis's ASCII table with all representations: \n");
    
    printf_s("\n  deci  hex  oct         binary   characters\n");            /* header for the table */

    for (c = 0; c <= 255; c++) 
    { 
        
        printf_s ("\n %3d    %2X   %03o   \t", c, c, c, c);                 /* print Ascii using for loop with multi representations */

        for (n = sizeof (c) * CHAR_BIT - 1; n >= 0; n--)                    /* method to convert decimal to base 2 (binary) */
            
            printf_s ("%d", ((c >> n) & 0x1) ? 1 : 0); 
            
            printf_s("%5c", c);       
        putchar ('\n');                                                     
        
        if(c==255)
        break;                /* to stop in 255 and not making infinite loop (because of unsigned char) */


    }

    putchar ('\n');                                                         

    return 0;
}
```

this is how my output look like

```
deci  hex  oct         binary   characters

   0     0   000        00000000

   1     1   001        00000001    ☺

   2     2   002        00000010    ☻

   3     3   003        00000011    ♥

   4     4   004        00000100    ♦

   5     5   005        00000101    ♣

   6     6   006        00000110    ♠

   7     7   007        00000111

   8     8   010        00001000

   9     9   011        00001001

  10     A   012        00001010


  11     B   013        00001011    ♂

  12     C   014        00001100    ♀

  13     D   015        00001101

  14     E   016        00001110    ♫

  15     F   017        00001111    ☼

  16    10   020        00010000    ►

  17    11   021        00010001    ◄

  18    12   022        00010010    ↕

  19    13   023        00010011    ‼

  20    14   024        00010100    ¶

  21    15   025        00010101    §

  22    16   026        00010110    ▬

  23    17   027        00010111    ↨

  24    18   030        00011000    ↑

  25    19   031        00011001    ↓

  26    1A   032        00011010    →

  27    1B   033        00011011

8    1C   034           00011100    ∟

  29    1D   035        00011101    ↔

  30    1E   036        00011110    ▲

  31    1F   037        00011111    ▼

  32    20   040        00100000

  33    21   041        00100001    !

  34    22   042        00100010    "

  35    23   043        00100011    #

  36    24   044        00100100    $

  37    25   045        00100101    %

  38    26   046        00100110    &

  39    27   047        00100111    '

  40    28   050        00101000    (

  41    29   051        00101001    )

  42    2A   052        00101010    *

  43    2B   053        00101011    +

  44    2C   054        00101100    ,

  45    2D   055        00101101    -

  46    2E   056        00101110    .

  47    2F   057        00101111    /

  48    30   060        00110000    0

  49    31   061        00110001    1

  50    32   062        00110010    2

  51    33   063        00110011    3

  52    34   064        00110100    4

  53    35   065        00110101    5

  54    36   066        00110110    6

  55    37   067        00110111    7

  56    38   070        00111000    8

  57    39   071        00111001    9

  58    3A   072        00111010    :

  59    3B   073        00111011    ;

  60    3C   074        00111100    <

  61    3D   075        00111101    =

  62    3E   076        00111110    >

  63    3F   077        00111111    ?

  64    40   100        01000000    @

  65    41   101        01000001    A

  66    42   102        01000010    B

  67    43   103        01000011    C

  68    44   104        01000100    D

  69    45   105        01000101    E

  70    46   106        01000110    F

  71    47   107        01000111    G

  72    48   110        01001000    H

  73    49   111        01001001    I

  74    4A   112        01001010    J

  75    4B   113        01001011    K

  76    4C   114        01001100    L

  77    4D   115        01001101    M

  78    4E   116        01001110    N

  79    4F   117        01001111    O

  80    50   120        01010000    P

  81    51   121        01010001    Q

  82    52   122        01010010    R

  83    53   123        01010011    S

  84    54   124        01010100    T

  85    55   125        01010101    U

  86    56   126        01010110    V

  87    57   127        01010111    W

  88    58   130        01011000    X

  89    59   131        01011001    Y

  90    5A   132        01011010    Z

  91    5B   133        01011011    [

  92    5C   134        01011100    \

  93    5D   135        01011101    ]

  94    5E   136        01011110    ^

  95    5F   137        01011111    _

  96    60   140        01100000    `

  97    61   141        01100001    a

  98    62   142        01100010    b

  99    63   143        01100011    c

 100    64   144        01100100    d

 101    65   145        01100101    e

 102    66   146        01100110    f

 103    67   147        01100111    g

 104    68   150        01101000    h

 105    69   151        01101001    i

 106    6A   152        01101010    j

 107    6B   153        01101011    k

 108    6C   154        01101100    l

 109    6D   155        01101101    m

 110    6E   156        01101110    n

 111    6F   157        01101111    o

 112    70   160        01110000    p

 113    71   161        01110001    q

 114    72   162        01110010    r

 115    73   163        01110011    s

 116    74   164        01110100    t

 117    75   165        01110101    u

 118    76   166        01110110    v

 119    77   167        01110111    w

 120    78   170        01111000    x

 121    79   171        01111001    y

 122    7A   172        01111010    z

 123    7B   173        01111011    {

 124    7C   174        01111100    |

 125    7D   175        01111101    }

 126    7E   176        01111110    ~

 127    7F   177        01111111    ⌂

 128    80   200        10000000    Ç

 129    81   201        10000001    ü

 130    82   202        10000010    é

 131    83   203        10000011    â

 132    84   204        10000100    ä

 133    85   205        10000101    à

 134    86   206        10000110    å

 135    87   207        10000111    ç

 136    88   210        10001000    ê

 137    89   211        10001001    ë

 138    8A   212        10001010    è

 139    8B   213        10001011    ï

 140    8C   214        10001100    î

 141    8D   215        10001101    ì

 142    8E   216        10001110    Ä

 143    8F   217        10001111    Å

 144    90   220        10010000    É

 145    91   221        10010001    æ

 146    92   222        10010010    Æ

 147    93   223        10010011    ô

 148    94   224        10010100    ö

 149    95   225        10010101    ò

 150    96   226        10010110    û

 151    97   227        10010111    ù

 152    98   230        10011000    ÿ

 153    99   231        10011001    Ö

 154    9A   232        10011010    Ü

 155    9B   233        10011011    ¢

 156    9C   234        10011100    £

 157    9D   235        10011101    ¥

 158    9E   236        10011110    ₧

 159    9F   237        10011111    ƒ

 160    A0   240        10100000    á

 161    A1   241        10100001    í

 162    A2   242        10100010    ó

 163    A3   243        10100011    ú

 164    A4   244        10100100    ñ

 165    A5   245        10100101    Ñ

 166    A6   246        10100110    ª

 167    A7   247        10100111    º

 168    A8   250        10101000    ¿

 169    A9   251        10101001    ⌐

 170    AA   252        10101010    ¬

 171    AB   253        10101011    ½

 172    AC   254        10101100    ¼

 173    AD   255        10101101    ¡

 174    AE   256        10101110    «

 175    AF   257        10101111    »

 176    B0   260        10110000    ░

 177    B1   261        10110001    ▒

 178    B2   262        10110010    ▓

 179    B3   263        10110011    │

 180    B4   264        10110100    ┤

 181    B5   265        10110101    ╡

 182    B6   266        10110110    ╢

 183    B7   267        10110111    ╖

 184    B8   270        10111000    ╕

 185    B9   271        10111001    ╣

 186    BA   272        10111010    ║

 187    BB   273        10111011    ╗

 188    BC   274        10111100    ╝

 189    BD   275        10111101    ╜

 190    BE   276        10111110    ╛

 191    BF   277        10111111    ┐

 192    C0   300        11000000    └

 193    C1   301        11000001    ┴

 194    C2   302        11000010    ┬

 195    C3   303        11000011    ├

 196    C4   304        11000100    ─

 197    C5   305        11000101    ┼

 198    C6   306        11000110    ╞

 199    C7   307        11000111    ╟

 200    C8   310        11001000    ╚

 201    C9   311        11001001    ╔

 202    CA   312        11001010    ╩

 203    CB   313        11001011    ╦

 204    CC   314        11001100    ╠

 205    CD   315        11001101    ═

 206    CE   316        11001110    ╬

 207    CF   317        11001111    ╧

 208    D0   320        11010000    ╨

 209    D1   321        11010001    ╤

 210    D2   322        11010010    ╥

 211    D3   323        11010011    ╙

 212    D4   324        11010100    ╘

 213    D5   325        11010101    ╒

 214    D6   326        11010110    ╓

 215    D7   327        11010111    ╫

 216    D8   330        11011000    ╪

 217    D9   331        11011001    ┘

 218    DA   332        11011010    ┌

 219    DB   333        11011011    █

 220    DC   334        11011100    ▄

 221    DD   335        11011101    ▌

 222    DE   336        11011110    ▐

 223    DF   337        11011111    ▀

 224    E0   340        11100000    α

 225    E1   341        11100001    ß

 226    E2   342        11100010    Γ

 227    E3   343        11100011    π

 228    E4   344        11100100    Σ

 229    E5   345        11100101    σ

 230    E6   346        11100110    µ

 231    E7   347        11100111    τ

 232    E8   350        11101000    Φ

 233    E9   351        11101001    Θ

 234    EA   352        11101010    Ω

 235    EB   353        11101011    δ

 236    EC   354        11101100    ∞

 237    ED   355        11101101    φ

 238    EE   356        11101110    ε

 239    EF   357        11101111    ∩

 240    F0   360        11110000    ≡

 241    F1   361        11110001    ±

 242    F2   362        11110010    ≥

 243    F3   363        11110011    ≤

 244    F4   364        11110100    ⌠

 245    F5   365        11110101    ⌡

 246    F6   366        11110110    ÷

 247    F7   367        11110111    ≈

 248    F8   370        11111000    °

 249    F9   371        11111001    ∙

 250    FA   372        11111010    ·

 251    FB   373        11111011    √

 252    FC   374        11111100    ⁿ

 253    FD   375        11111101    ²

 254    FE   376        11111110    ■

 255    FF   377        11111111
```

And the output I want it to be look like this

```
 deci  hex  oct         binary   characters

   0     0   000        00000000

   1     1   001        00000001    ☺

   2     2   002        00000010    ☻

   3     3   003        00000011    ♥

   4     4   004        00000100    ♦

   5     5   005        00000101    ♣

   6     6   006        00000110    ♠

   7     7   007        00000111

   8     8   010        00001000

   9     9   011        00001001

  10     A   012        00001010


  11     B   013        00001011    ♂

  12     C   014        00001100    ♀

  13     D   015        00001101

  14     E   016        00001110    ♫

  15     F   017        00001111    ☼

  16    10   020        00010000    ►

  17    11   021        00010001    ◄

  18    12   022        00010010    ↕

  19    13   023        00010011    ‼

  20    14   024        00010100    ¶

deci  hex  oct         binary   characters

  21    15   025        00010101    §

  22    16   026        00010110    ▬

  23    17   027        00010111    ↨

  24    18   030        00011000    ↑

  25    19   031        00011001    ↓

  26    1A   032        00011010    →

  27    1B   033        00011011

  28    1C   034        00011100    ∟

  29    1D   035        00011101    ↔

  30    1E   036        00011110    ▲

  31    1F   037        00011111    ▼

  32    20   040        00100000

  33    21   041        00100001    !

  34    22   042        00100010    "

  35    23   043        00100011    #

  36    24   044        00100100    $

  37    25   045        00100101    %

  38    26   046        00100110    &

  39    27   047        00100111    '

  40    28   050        00101000    (

deci  hex  oct         binary   characters

  41    29   051        00101001    )

  42    2A   052        00101010    *

  43    2B   053        00101011    +

  44    2C   054        00101100    ,

  45    2D   055        00101101    -

  46    2E   056        00101110    .

  47    2F   057        00101111    /

  48    30   060        00110000    0

  49    31   061        00110001    1

  50    32   062        00110010    2

  51    33   063        00110011    3

  52    34   064        00110100    4

  53    35   065        00110101    5

  54    36   066        00110110    6

  55    37   067        00110111    7

  56    38   070        00111000    8

  57    39   071        00111001    9

  58    3A   072        00111010    :

  59    3B   073        00111011    ;

  60    3C   074        00111100    <

deci  hex  oct         binary   characters

  61    3D   075        00111101    =

  62    3E   076        00111110    >

  63    3F   077        00111111    ?

  64    40   100        01000000    @

  65    41   101        01000001    A

  66    42   102        01000010    B

  67    43   103        01000011    C

  68    44   104        01000100    D

  69    45   105        01000101    E

  70    46   106        01000110    F

  71    47   107        01000111    G

  72    48   110        01001000    H

  73    49   111        01001001    I

  74    4A   112        01001010    J

  75    4B   113        01001011    K

  76    4C   114        01001100    L

  77    4D   115        01001101    M

  78    4E   116        01001110    N

  79    4F   117        01001111    O

  80    50   120        01010000    P

deci  hex  oct         binary   characters

  81    51   121        01010001    Q

  82    52   122        01010010    R

  83    53   123        01010011    S

  84    54   124        01010100    T

  85    55   125        01010101    U

  86    56   126        01010110    V

  87    57   127        01010111    W

  88    58   130        01011000    X

  89    59   131        01011001    Y

  90    5A   132        01011010    Z

  91    5B   133        01011011    [

  92    5C   134        01011100    \

  93    5D   135        01011101    ]

  94    5E   136        01011110    ^

  95    5F   137        01011111    _

  96    60   140        01100000    `

  97    61   141        01100001    a

  98    62   142        01100010    b

  99    63   143        01100011    c

 100    64   144        01100100    d

deci  hex  oct         binary   characters

 101    65   145        01100101    e

 102    66   146        01100110    f

 103    67   147        01100111    g

 104    68   150        01101000    h

 105    69   151        01101001    i

 106    6A   152        01101010    j

 107    6B   153        01101011    k

 108    6C   154        01101100    l

 109    6D   155        01101101    m

 110    6E   156        01101110    n

 111    6F   157        01101111    o

 112    70   160        01110000    p

 113    71   161        01110001    q

 114    72   162        01110010    r

 115    73   163        01110011    s

 116    74   164        01110100    t

 117    75   165        01110101    u

 118    76   166        01110110    v

 119    77   167        01110111    w

 120    78   170        01111000    x

deci  hex  oct         binary   characters

 121    79   171        01111001    y

 122    7A   172        01111010    z

 123    7B   173        01111011    {

 124    7C   174        01111100    |

 125    7D   175        01111101    }

 126    7E   176        01111110    ~

 127    7F   177        01111111    ⌂

 128    80   200        10000000    Ç

 129    81   201        10000001    ü

 130    82   202        10000010    é

 131    83   203        10000011    â

 132    84   204        10000100    ä

 133    85   205        10000101    à

 134    86   206        10000110    å

 135    87   207        10000111    ç

 136    88   210        10001000    ê

 137    89   211        10001001    ë

 138    8A   212        10001010    è

 139    8B   213        10001011    ï

 140    8C   214        10001100    î

deci  hex  oct         binary   characters

 141    8D   215        10001101    ì

 142    8E   216        10001110    Ä

 143    8F   217        10001111    Å

 144    90   220        10010000    É

 145    91   221        10010001    æ

 146    92   222        10010010    Æ

 147    93   223        10010011    ô

 148    94   224        10010100    ö

 149    95   225        10010101    ò

 150    96   226        10010110    û

 151    97   227        10010111    ù

 152    98   230        10011000    ÿ

 153    99   231        10011001    Ö

 154    9A   232        10011010    Ü

 155    9B   233        10011011    ¢

 156    9C   234        10011100    £

 157    9D   235        10011101    ¥

 158    9E   236        10011110    ₧

 159    9F   237        10011111    ƒ

 160    A0   240        10100000    á

deci  hex  oct         binary   characters

 161    A1   241        10100001    í

 162    A2   242        10100010    ó

 163    A3   243        10100011    ú

 164    A4   244        10100100    ñ

 165    A5   245        10100101    Ñ

 166    A6   246        10100110    ª

 167    A7   247        10100111    º

 168    A8   250        10101000    ¿

 169    A9   251        10101001    ⌐

 170    AA   252        10101010    ¬

 171    AB   253        10101011    ½

 172    AC   254        10101100    ¼

 173    AD   255        10101101    ¡

 174    AE   256        10101110    «

 175    AF   257        10101111    »

 176    B0   260        10110000    ░

 177    B1   261        10110001    ▒

 178    B2   262        10110010    ▓

 179    B3   263        10110011    │

 180    B4   264        10110100    ┤

deci  hex  oct         binary   characters

 181    B5   265        10110101    ╡

 182    B6   266        10110110    ╢

 183    B7   267        10110111    ╖

 184    B8   270        10111000    ╕

 185    B9   271        10111001    ╣

 186    BA   272        10111010    ║

 187    BB   273        10111011    ╗

 188    BC   274        10111100    ╝

 189    BD   275        10111101    ╜

 190    BE   276        10111110    ╛

 191    BF   277        10111111    ┐

 192    C0   300        11000000    └

 193    C1   301        11000001    ┴

 194    C2   302        11000010    ┬

 195    C3   303        11000011    ├

 196    C4   304        11000100    ─

 197    C5   305        11000101    ┼

 198    C6   306        11000110    ╞

 199    C7   307        11000111    ╟

 200    C8   310        11001000    ╚

deci  hex  oct         binary   characters


 201    C9   311        11001001    ╔

 202    CA   312        11001010    ╩

 203    CB   313        11001011    ╦

 204    CC   314        11001100    ╠

 205    CD   315        11001101    ═

 206    CE   316        11001110    ╬

 207    CF   317        11001111    ╧

 208    D0   320        11010000    ╨

 209    D1   321        11010001    ╤

 210    D2   322        11010010    ╥

 211    D3   323        11010011    ╙

 212    D4   324        11010100    ╘

 213    D5   325        11010101    ╒

 214    D6   326        11010110    ╓

 215    D7   327        11010111    ╫

 216    D8   330        11011000    ╪

 217    D9   331        11011001    ┘

 218    DA   332        11011010    ┌

 219    DB   333        11011011    █

 220    DC   334        11011100    ▄

deci  hex  oct         binary   characters

 221    DD   335        11011101    ▌

 222    DE   336        11011110    ▐

 223    DF   337        11011111    ▀

 224    E0   340        11100000    α

 225    E1   341        11100001    ß

 226    E2   342        11100010    Γ

 227    E3   343        11100011    π

 228    E4   344        11100100    Σ

 229    E5   345        11100101    σ

 230    E6   346        11100110    µ

 231    E7   347        11100111    τ

 232    E8   350        11101000    Φ

 233    E9   351        11101001    Θ

 234    EA   352        11101010    Ω

 235    EB   353        11101011    δ

 236    EC   354        11101100    ∞

 237    ED   355        11101101    φ

 238    EE   356        11101110    ε

 239    EF   357        11101111    ∩

 240    F0   360        11110000    ≡

deci  hex  oct         binary   characters

 241    F1   361        11110001    ±

 242    F2   362        11110010    ≥

 243    F3   363        11110011    ≤

 244    F4   364        11110100    ⌠

 245    F5   365        11110101    ⌡

 246    F6   366        11110110    ÷

 247    F7   367        11110111    ≈

 248    F8   370        11111000    °

 249    F9   371        11111001    ∙

 250    FA   372        11111010    ·

 251    FB   373        11111011    √

 252    FC   374        11111100    ⁿ

 253    FD   375        11111101    ²

 254    FE   376        11111110    ■

 255    FF   377        11111111
```

Comment: Use the modulo operator: `if (c % 20 == 0) printf("deci  hex  oct         binary   characters\n");`

Comment: Include `<limits.h>` instead of trying to define your own value for `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: You will run into problems trying to display characters with ASCII values > 127 as there is no guarantee that a terminal character set support extended ASCII (less and less do since we no longer use the ASCII drawing character for text mode windowing apps. ASCII characters are those with character values from 0-127. I've always been fond of [ASCII Chart - 4 Column Char, Dec, Oct, Hex](https://pastebin.com/RyXmUXDQ) (which includes special chars 0-31)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef CHAR_BIT
#define CHAR_BIT 8  
#endif

int main () {

    unsigned char c = 0;     /* for the character */
    int n = 0;              /* integer for the for loop Iteration */

    printf("\nthis's ASCII table with all representations: \n");

    for (c = 0; c <= 255; c++) 
    { 
        if (c%20 == 0)
            printf("\n  deci  hex  oct         binary   characters\n");


        printf ("\n %3d    %2X   %03o   \t", c, c, c);                 /* print Ascii using for loop with multi representations */

        for (n = sizeof (c) * CHAR_BIT - 1; n >= 0; n--){                    /* method to convert decimal to base 2 (binary) */
            printf ("%d", ((c >> n) & 0x1) ? 1 : 0); 
        }    
        printf("%5c", c);       
        putchar ('\n');                                                     

        if(c==255)
        break;                /* to stop in 255 and not making infinite loop (because of unsigned char) */

    }

    putchar ('\n');                                                         

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, missed it. Thanks, updated.

Comment: `c <= 255` *"comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]"*